# Unable to login through custom app (tabs) built in Microsoft teams app studio

Tags: microsoft-teams

We built a custom application in App Studio in Microsoft Teams for organisation needs. Basically, we made a tab which displays a website. This website auth with login.microsoftonline.com and then redirect to our website on success.

When we are accessing the website in the browser or teams (Web version) we are able to see the login screen and we are able to login and continue as usual. (Please find the attached screenshot below for reference)

[Web Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSbrh.jpg)

Whereas, when we are trying to access the same from Microsoft Teams desktop, it is displaying a empty page instead of login page. (Please find the attached screenshot below for reference)

[Microsoft Teams App Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF8a4.jpg)

We even added *.microsoftlogin.com as a valid domain while creating custom app in app studio. Is there anyway we can show the login to make it work.

Thank you

Comment: The error displayed here, seems to be an iframe issue, Have you implemented teams tab authentication in your custom app? Did you added "*.login.microsoftonline.com"in validDomain array?

Comment: Hi Trinetra, Thanks for the reply. We have added *.login.microsoftonline.com as a valid domain in app manifest. Can you please provide information regarding  **teams tab authentication in your custom app**. Currently we are calling microsoft login api from our website, we are directly showing login.

We found one intermediate issue, this blank screen issue is occurring if user tries for the first time. Suppose, we user already login in website then the app is bypassing the login automatically.

Comment: Hi @Trinetra-MSFT, I found Microsoft teams documentation in which it is mentioned that we need to use pop-up window [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab). Is this the teams tab authentication your referring ?. Is there any way in tabs to check if it is opened from teams desktop or teams browser so that i can you pop-up method in desktop and normal existing login process in web version.

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw your comment, Yes that is the correct documentation, Once you implement tab auth in your app, it will work for web & desktop, also you can check in tab context it is for web or desktop.

Comment: @Nagasai were you able to figure out the issue? I am having a similar issue with authentication in Teams.